# Labels printing to wrong cells in table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm fetching stocks from YQL with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON, saving them to my Core Data "Company" object, and then using the data in labels like so:

Attempted code:

```
func fetchStocks() {

let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Company", in: managedContext)!
var prices = [String]()

if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20symbol%2C%20Ask%2C%20YearHigh%2C%20YearLow%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22TWTR%22%2C%22TSLA%22%2C%20%22FB%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")!) {
    let json = JSON(data: data)
    print(json)
    if let appleStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][0]["Ask"].string {
        prices.append(appleStockPrice)
    }
    if let googleStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][1]["Ask"].string {
        prices.append(googleStockPrice)
    }
    if let twitterStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][2]["Ask"].string {
        prices.append(twitterStockPrice)
    }
    if let teslaStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][3]["Ask"].string {
        prices.append(teslaStockPrice)
    }
    if let facebookStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][4]["Ask"].string {
        prices.append(facebookStockPrice)
    }
    for stocks in prices {
        let company = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,insertInto: managedContext)
        company.setValue(stocks, forKey: "stockPrice")
        companies.append(company)
    }
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        vc.tableView.reloadData()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
}
```

And when I try to set the prices to detail text labels with

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! Cell
    let company = companies[indexPath.row]


    cell.textLabel?.text = company.value(forKey: "name") as? String

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Current stock price: \(company.value(forKey: "stockPrice") as? String)"

    return cell
}
```

I get this:

[image]

So the stock prices are getting fetched, but not getting placed in the cells with the companies - instead, those values are nil, and the stock prices go into separate cells.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

EDIT: Posted whole cellForRow method, and here is the YQL JSON:

```
{
  "query" : {
"created" : "2017-01-24T18:12:06Z",
"results" : {
  "quote" : [
    {
      "symbol" : "AAPL",
      "YearLow" : "89.470",
      "YearHigh" : "120.810",
      "Ask" : "119.990"
    },
    {
      "symbol" : "GOOG",
      "YearLow" : "663.06",
      "YearHigh" : "824.87",
      "Ask" : "821.70"
    },
    {
      "symbol" : "TWTR",
      "YearLow" : "13.73",
      "YearHigh" : "25.25",
      "Ask" : null
    },
    {
      "symbol" : "TSLA",
      "YearLow" : "141.0500",
      "YearHigh" : "269.3400",
      "Ask" : "253.4100"
    },
    {
      "symbol" : "FB",
      "YearLow" : "94.23",
      "YearHigh" : "133.50",
      "Ask" : "128.67"
    }
  ]
},
"count" : 5,
"lang" : "en-us"
  }
}
```

EDIT 2: Setting the names, logos & stockPrices

```
func setDefaultCompanies() {

    // Default 5 companies at launch - user can delete/add/edit

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let defaultValues = ["firstRun" : true]
    userDefaults.register(defaults: defaultValues)

    if userDefaults.bool(forKey: "firstRun") {

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Company", in: managedContext)!
        let defaultCompanies = ["Apple", "Google", "Facebook", "Tesla", "Twitter"]

        for companyName in defaultCompanies {
            let company = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,insertInto: managedContext)
            company.setValue(companyName, forKey: "name")
            company.setValue(companyName, forKey: "logo")
            companies.append(company)
        }
        fetchStocks()
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            userDefaults.set(false, forKey: "firstRun")
            vc.tableView.reloadData()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show us the whole code of `cellForRowAtindexPath`.

Comment: Paste the whole cellForRow method. Also the example json would help

Comment: I edited to add cellForRow and the JSON (Alistra I think you were asking for the JSON returned from the YQL request, let me know if you meant something different)

Comment: You are creating `NSManagedObject` instances only with the quotes. Where are the names assigned?

Comment: @vadian You actually helped me with the names a few days ago, I'll edit my question here to show that code (the fetchStocks function is called in there as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code cannot work. You are doing the following:

- Create the default companies (adding 5 `NSManagedObject` instances)
- Fetch the stock values.
- Create new companies (adding another 5 `NSManagedObject` instances).

Now you have 10 entries instead of 5.

---

My suggestion:

- Create a file `Localizable.strings` to map the company symbols to the real names

  ```
  "AAPL" = "Apple";
  "TSLA" = "Tesla";
  "TWTR" = "Twitter";
  "GOOG" = "Google";
  "FB" = "FaceBook";
  ```
- Then get **first** the stock values.
- In the loop get the real name from the key `symbol` via `NSLocalizedString(comment:)`, create the `NSManagedObject` instance and set the attributes.

This uses an asynchronous way to load the data and replaces `setDefaultCompanies()` **and** `fetchStocks()` (untested)

```
func setDefaultCompanies() {

    // Default 5 companies at launch - user can delete/add/edit

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let defaultValues = ["firstRun" : true]
    userDefaults.register(defaults: defaultValues)

    if userDefaults.bool(forKey: "firstRun") {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Company", in: managedContext)!

        let url = URL(string: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20symbol%2C%20Ask%2C%20YearHigh%2C%20YearLow%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22TWTR%22%2C%22TSLA%22%2C%20%22FB%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!) // or display an alert view
            } else if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                let json = JSON(data: data!)
                if let quotes = json["query"]["results"]["quote"].array {
                    for quote in quotes {
                        let symbol = quote["symbol"].stringValue
                        let name = NSLocalizedString(symbol, comment:"")
                        let ask = quote["Ask"].stringValue
                        let company = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,insertInto: self.managedContext)
                        company.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
                        company.setValue(name, forKey: "logo")
                        company.setValue(ask, forKey: "stockPrice")
                        self.companies.append(company)
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       do {
                           try self.managedContext.save()
                           self.vc.tableView.reloadData()
                           userDefaults.set(false, forKey: "firstRun")
                       } catch let error as NSError {
                           print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                       }
                   }
                }
            } else {
                print("The data couldn't be loaded") // or display an alert view
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the right way to go about doing it. You don't want to create "default companies", you should try to create the companies after you get the stock values.

Comment: @vadian Thanks! I'll have to read up on localized strings and then try this solution. Thanks for all your help recently.

Comment: @vadian I just did a tutorial on localized strings - cool stuff! Your solution works as well, although interestingly it only works if I put a print statement at the end of the for loop. If there's no print statement I just get an empty table view. Adding a print statement gets it to work, but nothing is printed to the console. Maybe a weird bug but regardless your solution worked so thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your cells are not being dequeued correctly. This problem appears only when cells are scrolled in the tableview but not dequeued to retain its content.

Comment: The cells are dequeued with `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! Cell`, is there a different way?

Comment: Reusing cells is not the actual issue.